# Flag button not working on BlackBerry 10

Tags: bug, status-completed

Using the [BlackBerry 10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry_10) built-in browser, I can't hit the flag button on Stack Exchange sites. The edit button next to it works perfectly, but the word 'flag' is behaving as though it's not a link of any sort at all. Nothing of any sort happens when I click on it, not even the highlighting that the browser uses to help you make sure you've hit the right link, which suggests that it's the link, not the resulting popup.